# Calculating expected gamma attenuation without a specific energy level

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering, gamma-rays

I am trying to calculate 2 things for a science experiment involving radiation and shielding using a geiger counter.

A) whether the reduction in counts per minute through a measured thickness of lead or acrylic observed myself matches established models of attenuation

B) Whether I can detect an increased efficiency in shielding when acrylic and lead is used in a way that accounts for bremsstrahlung radiation when compared to the expected attenuation coefficients of the sum of the 2 materials combined.

Unfortunately I only have a pancake geiger counter and do not have a gamma scintillator. The radiation source I am using is a Urano-polychrase crystal (U<sup>4+</sup>,Y)(Ti,Nb)<sub>2</sub>O<sub>6</sub>.

What equations would I need to calculate this? Is it even possible with the equipment I have?

Some problems which I see and don't know how to solve:

1) How do you calculate attenuation when you don't know the electron volts it's emitting. Can I take the average of an established ore?

2) How do I combine models of attenuation for both beta and gamma?

3) How do I calculate whether any difference is a significant difference (I was never good at chi square equations and have not done them in a while)

Planned test methodology so far:
Calculate alpha, beta, and gamma proportions of the source by shielding the sensor with nothing, paper and aluminium.

Measure reduction in cpm of varying thicknesses of just acrylic, just lead, lead first acrylic second, and acrylic first lead second.

Use data of acrylic only and lead only to see whether my measurements match established attenuation models and calculate my own attenuation coefficient for the materials based on the data I took and established models.

See whether bremsstrahlung radiation is a detectable factor by comparing the lead first acrylic second and acrylic second and lead first data as well as using the coefficients I calculated to see whether acrylic first lead second beats out a theoretical model which does not account for bremsstrahlung radiation.

So tldr: Is it possible to see whether my own shielding tests matches established models and see if I can detect any effects of bremsstrahlung radiation all without spectrometry or a pure isotope?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible. You need to know the gamma energies. Why can't you look up the gamma spectrum of whatever uranium isotope you're using?

Comment: @BenCrowell The sample I am using only has uranium in it. Can I get a spectrograph from somewhere online and use it? How close do i have to get to what it actually is, can I use a graph of the mix of 235/238 or do I have to get a spectrograph of the exact mineral? If a spectrograph of just uranium does not cut it can I get away with a graph of a similar mineral? As far as obtaining a graph goes I could also get a specimen of uraninite which I bet there is a lot more data on and wanted to get anyways.